# not in range if statement printing in range floating points

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with a simple Python script. The script has a list input of temperatures and I want to print all temperatures which are outside of 0 to 5.

This works fine until I input a floating point. For example, if the list has 1, 4, 6, -2, it only prints 6 and -2 as expected. If I input 1, 4, 4.3, 6, it prints out 4.3 and 6.

I understand that this problem is related to floating points and for some reason why if not statement is letting through floating points. I have searched high and low but no luck although I am sure it's very simple.

Do you know why this is the case?

```
# input for temperatures
temperatures = [1, 4, 4.3,6]

# empty output list
output_list = []

for temperature in temperatures:
    if temperature not in range (0,6):
        output_list = output_list + [temperature]
# print the output_list
print(output_list)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Apart from the range issue clarified in the answers, you can simply use  `output_list.append(temperature)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `range()` function outputs only numbers with steps of 1 by default.

For example, `range(4)` returns `0, 1, 2, 3`. Compare this to `range(2, 4)` which returns `2, 3` and `range(2, 4, 0.5)` which returns `2, 2.5, 3, 3.5`.

For your question, a better solution would replace the `if temperature not in range (0,6):` into `if not 0 <= temperature <= 5:`.

Here's your whole code fixed:
Thanks @Bazingaa for noticing the error. (Thanks for suggesting `.append()` too.)

```
# input for temperatures
temperatures = [1, 4, 4.3,6]

# empty output list
output_list = []

for temperature in temperatures:
    if not 0 <= temperature <= 5:
        output_list.append(temperature)
# print the output_list
print(output_list)
```

Note a simpler list comprehension here:

```
output_list = [temp for temp in temperatures if not 0 <= temperature <= 5]
```

Comment: `if 0 <= temperature <= 5:` is wrong. The correct version needed is `if not 0 <= temperature <= 5:`. Also `output_list = output_list + [temperature]` can simply be replaced by `output_list.append(temperature)`

Comment: Oh noo. Sorry about that. I'll change it so it returns the right values.

Answer (score 5):

`temperature not in range (0,6)` means temperature is not one of the values in `range(0,6)`, which is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

What you actually want to check is not whether the value is one of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but whether it is >= 0 and <= 5. So, do this:

```
if not 0 <= temperature <= 5:
    ...
```

---

BTW, to understand more clearly what `range` does, try this:

```
>>> print(list(range(0, 6)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a floating point bug. It is related to `range` being an iterable. `4.3` is included in the output because it is not in the iterable. The statement checking if a temperature is in the range would return `3` if the range was `range(0, 6, 2)`.

A better solution would be as follows

```
# input for temperatures
temperatures = [1, 4, 4.3,6]

# empty output list
output_list = []

temp_range = list(range(0, 6))

for temperature in temperatures:
    if min(temp_range) >= temperature or max(temp_range) <= temperature:
        output_list = output_list + [temperature]
# print the output_list
print(output_list)
```